# How to expose Swagger UI without authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, permissions, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to make the SwaggerUi interface not ask for authorization every time I boot.

I tried to enter in my Configure class:

`.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**","/mypath/**").permitAll()`

and

```
 .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/mypath/**").permitAll()
```

but without success.

Actuator on the other hand works fine without authorization with this code structure

Thanks everyone for a possible answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that even in the Sprinc-doc documentation they put you the case that you entered too. In order to make the code work you have to enter multiple permissions, one for each path. In your case it will have to be something like this:

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**","/v2/**","/mypath/**","/swagger.yml","/anypath/").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
```

Then just go here:

```
http://localhost:[YOUR PORT]/swagger-ui/
```

p.s Don't forget the / at the end of the URL :)

Comment: Hi Renis , unfortunately it doesn't work and keeps asking me for credentials

Comment: Do you use any other URL definers such as :
`server.servlet.context-path=/api` in your application.properties file?
If so, then you have to write it like this: `http://localhost:[YOUR PORT]/api/swagger-ui/`

Comment: This is my custom URL : springdoc.swagger-ui.path: /docs/swagger-ui.html , how should i write?

Comment: First of all if you are using Springfox Swagger2 then the correct way to set the path is:
`springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.base-url= //path// `
Second add the complete custom path to your security configurations:
`.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/docs/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()`
P.S you don't need .html at the end

Comment: I use OpenApi3 for Swagger

Comment: Hmm,
I've only worked with Springfox, but I don't think it matters.
Can you check the endpoints that your App creates via your IDE ?

Comment: When I try to login to docs / swagger-ui / it asks me for credentials and redirects me to this "localhost:8083/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config "

Comment: Try
`authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/docs/**").permitAll()`
And take care of the order of the authorizations, they matter,put this as the first one